# AT&T Assembly Syntax in C program (Mingw gcc)

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, mingw, x86-64

This simple program((AT&T Assembly Syntax) ) works fine on Linux, but compiles on windows with an error。

```
.section .text
.type add,@function
.global add
 add:
     pushq  %rbp
     movq   %rsp, %rbp
     movl   %ecx, 16(%rbp)
     movl   16(%rbp), %eax
     imull  %eax, %eax
     popq   %rbp
     ret
```

The error is in the second line:

```
.type add,@function
```

this pseudo-command will report an error under windows with the following error message,use MinGw gcc:

```
add.S:2: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
add.S:2: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `a'
```

This is so strange and I want to know why?

Comment: Windows doesn't use ELF.

Comment: You don't need that `.type` line on Windows. I'm not sure if it's completely optional on Linux, but I haven't actually wrote that line when writing assembly routines on Linux.

Comment: it will fail on linux as well depending on the tools.

Comment: nothing is surprising here yet, please provide a complete example

Comment: at&t syntax is not relevant here.  nor is x86...yet